# Spring, PagingAndSortingRepository, findOne with @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Hi i have following Entity with EmbeddedId id (I am using lombok for getters, setters and constructors) :

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SignUpIdentity implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Getter @Setter
    @JoinColumn(name="training")
    @ManyToOne
    private Training training;

    @NotNull
    @Getter @Setter
    @JoinColumn(name="user")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

}

@Entity
public class SignUp{

    @EmbeddedId
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private SignUpIdentity signUpIdentity;

    @Getter
    private Date date;

    public SignUp () {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.date = cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

I have also a Paging and Sorting repository and a controller:

```
public interface SignUpRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SignUp, SignUpIdentity> {

}


@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/signUps")
public class SignUpController {
    @Autowired
    SignUpRepository signUpRepository;

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody SignUp createOrUpdate(@RequestBody SignUp titemBody) {
        return signUpRepository.save(titemBody);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/find", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public SignUp readById(@RequestBody SignUpIdentity id) {
        return signUpRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenewer i send POST request to /signUps/find it doesn't return any results, even though it should (i've added signup with training: 2 and user: "1234"). This is the body of the request i am making:

```
{
   "training": {"id": 2},
   "user": {"phoneNumber": "1234"}
}
```

These is the response:

```
{
"timestamp": 1518693385312,
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/signUps/find"
}
```

What am i missing?

These are user and training entities:

```
@Entity
public class Training {
    @Id
    @Getter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Getter @Setter
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Getter
    private Date dateOfInsert;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="signUpIdentity.training")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Getter @Setter
    private Set<SignUp> signUp;

    public Training() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateOfInsert = cal.getTime();
    }

    public Training(long id) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateOfInsert = cal.getTime();
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter
    private String phoneNumber;

    @NotNull
    @Getter @Setter
    private String nameAndSurname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="signUpIdentity.user")
    @Getter @Setter
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<SignUp> signUp;

    public User() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.date = cal.getTime();
    }
}
```

I even made my custon find in repository, but it still doesnt return me anything:

```
@Query("select u from SignUp u where u.signUpIdentity.training.id = :trainingId and u.signUpIdentity.user.phoneNumber = :phoneNumber")
SignUp findByTrainingAndUser(@Param("trainingId") long trainingId,
                           @Param("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber);
```

---

```
@RequestMapping(path="/find", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public SignUp readById(@RequestBody SignUpIdentity id) {
      return signUpRepository.findByTrainingAndUser(id.getTraining().getId(), id.getUser().getPhoneNumber());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be more simple and easy to just send  the Id in your request like this

{
  "id": 2
}

and update your method in the controller to search with just ID

Comment: I must have EmbededId that consist of Training and User and i also would like to find given SignUp by training.id and user.phoneNumber

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `SignUpRepository` to use a Long type in the generic interface.

```
public interface SignUpRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SignUp, 
 Long> {

 }
```